# javascript (node.js) convert url hash to url with parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a large static result and I'm trying the following changes:

- Replace the original domain to another one.
- Convert url's hash to url with parameters using the post id only for a specific domain (website.com).

This is my original static result example with 3 links and 2 differents domain names:

```
var json = {This is the static result with many links like this <a href=\"http://website.com/932427/post/something-else/\" target=\"_blank\"> and this is other link obviusly with another post id <a href=\"http://website.com/456543/post/another-something-else/\" target=\"_blank\">, this is another reference from another domain <a href=\"http://onother-website.com/23423/post/please-ingnore-this-domain/\" target=\"_blank\"> }
```

So, the originals url's I need to change are two, according with the above example:

```
http://website.com/932427/post/something-else/ 
http://website.com/456542/post/another-something-else/
```

And I want to change that links now with this format:

```
http://other_domain.com/id?=932427/
http://other_domain.com/id?=456543/
```

And the final result should look like this into the static result.

By the way I'm using node.js

Thanks in advance

Comment: DO you try to do something?

Comment: Do you mean a redirect? Do you use any framework for the HTTP?

Comment: `json` does not look like real JSON. Take a look at regular expressions (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). You'll then be able to find required links and replace/reformat them in a certain way you need it.

Comment: @FUserThrowError Sure, I'll trying with this option: 

var url = "http://website.com/932427/post/something-else/";
var re3 = /\/news.urban360.com.mx\/(\d+)/;
var found = url.match(re3);
console.log(JSON.stringify(found));

However just change the first coincidence.
var found = url.match(re3);

Comment: @Bergi Nop, i dont looking for redirect, i looking for change the original urls into the result static, on the another hand I use express.

Comment: @Micha Radonov Sure, the var Json is just for example propouses, the original is a little bit large and well formed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Node.js has a built in module for parsing and constructing URLs. Your solution can be written as:

```
var url = require('url'); // Comes with Node.

// Get the path: '/932427/post/something-else/'
var path = url.parse('http://website.com/932427/post/something-else/').path; 

var newUrl = url.format({
    protocol: 'http',
    host: 'other_domain.com',
    query: { id: path.split('/')[1] }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all links follow the same pattern and your json object looks like this

```
var json = {
    urls: [
        'http://website.com/932427/post/something-else/',
        'http://website.com/456542/post/another-something-else/'     
    ]
};
```

You could use a simple regex to extract the ids and construct your new links like this

```
var idPattern = /\/(\d{6})\//; // matches 6 digits inside slashes
var newUrlFormat = 'http://other_domain.com/id?={id}/';
var newUrls = [];

json.urls.forEach(function (url) {
    var id = idPattern.exec(url)[1];
    newUrls.push(newUrlFormat.replace('{id}', id))
});
```

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9ThH/) to try it out.

Comment: Thaks, I will try it!.

Comment: this will work but is certainly not a robust solution. Much better to use Node.js built-ins, see other answer.

Comment: I don't think my solution is less robust, but I agree that using built in NodeJS modules is a better way to go. It also makes for more readable code. I upvoted the other answer.